# Recursion counter failing to ++

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array

As home work I was assigned to make a static method which counts how many variations is there for placing a domino piece inside a 2 by N table.

rules:
- It has to be recursive.
- No support methods, but overloading is ok.
- No static variables
- No support arrays

That's what I made so far:

```
    public static int domino(int n, int m) {
    int[][] board = new int[m][n];
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("##Checking c2:");
    if (n >= 2) {
        System.out.println("fitting a c2");
        sum += Ex14.domino(n-2,m,sum);
    }
    else {
        sum++;
        System.out.println("can't fit a c2");
    }
    System.out.println("##Checking c1:");
    if (n >= 1) {
        System.out.println("fitting a c1");
        sum  += Ex14.domino(n-1,m, sum);
    }
    else {
        sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}`
```

this is the overloading method:

```
public static int domino(int n,int m,int sum) {
    int[][] board = new int[m][n];
    if (n >= 2) {
        System.out.println("fitting a c2");
        Ex14.domino(n-2,m,sum);
    }
    if (n>= 1) {
        System.out.println("fitting a c1");
        Ex14.domino(n-1,m,sum);
    }
    else {
        sum++;
        System.out.println("Current Sum is: " + sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

what the code does is checking if it can add either c2 ( 2 columns piece) or c1 (one coulmn piece) and call itself with a smaller table.
once it can no longer fit either c1 or c2 it due to N below 1 it adds 1 to the sum (sum++).

for some reason it works on a 2x2 table but not on a 2x3 or 2x4. I added the "fitting c1/2" and "current sum" to debug where is the problem and it seems to not run the sum++ even when it reaches it.

any tips?

Comment: just to get the obvious out of the way, you are passing n = 4 and m = 2 for the 2x4 array and n=3 and m=2 for the 2x3 array?  Also what happens when you try a 3x2 or 3x4 array

Comment: In your overloaded method, you are calling the method recursively, but not using the value it returns in any way. So whatever calculation it does is not taken into consideration.

Comment: Can you maybe give some expected output for different table sizes?

Comment: @RealSkeptic is spot on with that (not sure how I missed it).

Comment: @RealSkeptic if you mean adding sum+= at the overloaded method: 
tried it now 2x2 returns 4 instead of 2. tried removing the sum+= from the original method, and it returns 3 instaed of 2.

Keiwan 2x2 = 2, 2x3 = 3, 2x4 = 5

Comment: @RealSkeptic Nevermind, got what you meant now it looks like it works. switched all sum+= to sum= and it works now a thanks a lot!!